# Generating Compiler replay data file for Java high memory usage during C2 compilation

Tags: java, jvm, compiler-optimization, jit

C2 compiler thread is allocating high memory(Confirmed with the help of Native memory tracking) while compiling a few methods. Issue is reproduced randomly and not able to replicate with a test code.

The compilations are actually getting failed with: COMPILE SKIPPED: unsupported calling sequence (retry at different tier)

How to record the state of JVM and dump the so called "Compiler_replay_data" file during this problematic compilation?

In a few JDK bug reports on JVM crash, could see the replay file is very much helpful. How to generate one such for my high memory footprint case?

Comment: What version and distribution of the JDK are you using? What are the arguments used to start it? Please share the full literal error message. Are you seeing it in the logs?

Comment: @aled Zulu JDK 11 it is. Have enabled PrintCompilation and nothing specific to compilation. This particular message is thrown out by PrintCompilation. 

5021138 1171   !   4       sample.SampleClass::sampleMethod (6090 bytes)   COMPILE SKIPPED: unsupported calling sequence (retry at different tier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `-XX:CompileCommand` to enable recording of replay data for the particular method:

```
java -XX:CompileCommand=option,ClassName::methodName,DumpReplay ...
```

`ClassName` and/or `methodName` may be specified as a wildcard with `*`. E.g., to dump replay data for all `java.lang` classes, use

```
java -XX:CompileCommand=option,java.lang.*::*,DumpReplay ...
```

Replay data is also automatically saved if JVM crashes during JIT compilation. You may force JVM crash on the compilation failure with the following option:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+AbortVMOnCompilationFailure ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is providing the required output.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm facing this error while replaying:
"'ReplayCompiles' is develop and is available only in debug version of VM."

So need to recompile the JDK in some other way?

Comment: @vkm Yes, JDK needs to be built with `--enable-debug` option, or you can try prebuilt `fastdebug` binaries from https://builds.shipilev.net